# Initialization and Scope in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, scope

The code bellow won't be compiled and the Swift compiler will show an error: `"Variable 'firstVar' used before being initialized"`.

```
var firstVar: Double
var secondVar = 2.0

if 1 > 0 {
    firstVar = 2.0
}

print(firstVar)
```

At the same time the Swift compiler (2.2) has no problem with the following code, it prints `"Hello, Stack Overflow"`. For the Swift 3.0, the following code will show an error as expected.

```
var firstVar: Double
var secondVar = 2.0

if 1 > 0 {
    firstVar = 2.0
}

if secondVar > 1.0 && firstVar > 0 {
    print("Hello, stackoverflow!")
}
```

Could you explain, why the second condition of the if-statement in the second code example evaluates to true and the compiler (Swift 2.2) doesn't complain about the `firstVar` being initialized while in the first code example it does.

Comment: For Swift 3.0 you get an (expected) error for both cases, for the 2nd one with the error message _"variable '`firstVar`' captured by a closure before being initialized"_. I haven't tested in Swift 2.2, but possibly this was a bug that has not been resolved.

Comment: Interesting, for the Swift 2.2, the compiler prints "Hello, stackoverflow!", for the Swift 3.0 it doesn't.

Comment: @dfri  "captured by a closure before being initialized" is also giving in  sift 2.2 in xcode project but not giving in playground.

Comment: The _"captured by a closure"_ part most likely comes from the fact that the the right hand side (`rhs`) of `&&` operator is implemented lazily and also using `@autoclosure`. If you switch the positions of the `lhs` and `rhs` in the second `if` statement above, you get the more expected error _"variable 'firstVar' used before being initialized"_. The reason why the above example dont yield and error in a playground is probably that the `rhs` is never evaluated, as `lhs` is `true`, allowing short-circuiting (and no "look ahead" by the playground "real-time compiler").

Comment: @dfri It would be implemented lazily if the the right hand side `(rhs)` of `||` operator was `true`. For the `&&`, both values from both sides have to be evaluated to `true`, so the whole condition is evaluated to `true`. Am I not right?

Comment: You're right, I was a bit too quick there! I'm not at home so I cannot test in a playground myself (only the IBM sandbox), but it's possible that the playgrounds "compilation" can't peek further into lazy implementations (hence cannot know we actually make use of an possibly non-assigned value in the `rhs` autoclosure). During the "runtime" that follows the quick playground compilation, the value turns out to have (luckily) been initialized by the time we execute the `rhs` of `&&`; hence no error in the playground (whereas error if we actually compile the project outside of the playground).

Comment: @dfri Could check the problem in the playground when you get home, that would be great!

Comment: That'll be some time from now (~10hrs), but if no one has verified this by then I'll look into it! (I'm quite certain what we discussed above is the reason for this behavior; playgrounds can act quite strange w.r.t. projects).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was a friday and I totally forgot about this after work :) Added an anser for this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Delaying the evaluation of an expression by wrapping it in a closure: limitations of the Swift playground's on-the-fly "compilation" lets this erroneous program flow pass without error

The `rhs` expression of `&&` (`= firstVar`) is automatically wrapped in a closure (here: using `autoclosure`), which means the evaluation of `firstVar` is delayed (lazily), such that your examples will "compile" when using the on-the-fly compilation of the Swift Playground. I can speculate that even preconditions for the correctness of lazy evaluations will be checked only at *runtime*, and not at compile time, when using the Swift Playground.

When attempting the same in an actual project, the compiler needn't restrain itself to quick on-the-fly compilation, and can spot the compile time error for what it is:

> *"error: variable '`...`' captured by a closure before being initialized"*

I.e., the above shouldn't compile, but does actually run fine due to the conditional initialization of `firstVar` in the body of the `if` statement. Note that the fact that `1 > 0` is `true` should not affect the fact that this is a compile time error, as evaluating the state of `1 > 0` is *a runtime decision*.

---

**Details**

The logical binary infix operator `'&&'` has a right had side `rhs` that is implemented lazily, with `@autoclosure`

```
func &&(lhs: BooleanType, @autoclosure rhs: () -> BooleanType) -> Bool {
    return lhs.boolValue ? rhs().boolValue : false
}
```

From [The Language Reference - Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html):

> **`autoclosure`**
>
> This attribute is used to **delay the evaluation of an expression** *by
>   automatically wrapping that expression in a closure with no arguments*.
>   Apply this attribute to a parameter declaration for a function or
>   method type that takes no arguments and that returns the type of the
>   expression. Declarations with the `autoclosure` attribute imply
>   `noescape` as well, except when passed the optional attribute argument
>   `escaping`.

We can show the behaviour of your example even more clearly by the following example:

```
var foo: Double

/* use autoclosure to capture the argument in a closure */
func bar(@autoclosure arg: () -> Double) {
    print(arg())
}

/* or let the user explicitly supply the argument in a closure form */
func baz(arg: () -> Double) {
    print(arg())
}

if true {
    foo = 1.0
}

bar(foo)        // 1.0, OK in Playground, error when in a project
baz() { foo }   // 1.0, OK in Playground, error when in a project
```